# Pass a input value with url in php

Tags: php, web

I want to pass a input value with a url.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="myDiv" class="answer_list">
        <form action="" id="usrform" method="get">
            <textarea name="comment" style="width: 450px; height: 80px; form="usrform"></textarea>

   <?php echo '<a href="reject_request.php?leave_id='.$id1.'&emp_id='.$emp_id.'">'?>
   <button style="float: right" type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">
        Proceed
    </button></a></form></div>
</div>
```

---

Here I want to pass the textarea input value to 'reject_request.php' page with other variables. I couldn't able to find a way, Can any one help me !

Comment: `<form action="reject_request.php" ...` ?

Comment: Its not good habit to post textarea long content in url..instead post form to reject_request.php on anchor tag click

Comment: So how can I get its value?

Comment: you can get the value via GET/POST variable.ex-$_GET['value'] or $_POST['value']

Comment: But it does not work in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `method="POST"` and `action="reject_request.php"`

```
<form action="reject_request.php" id="usrform" method="POST">
  <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="leave_id" id="leave_id" value="<?php echo $id1; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="emp_id" id="emp_id" value="<?php echo $emp_id; ?>">
 </form>
```

In `reject_request.php` you can access the form datas via `$_POST['comment'],$_POST['leave_id'],$_POST['emp_id']`

Comment: That was exactly what I want. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not advisable to pass long content in URL, as commented by @Dhara Parmar.

But if you want to do it,

```
<form action = "yourpage.php" .... as, again, commented by splash 58
```

As far as accessing those variables are concerned, you can access them via ASSOCIATIVE GLOBAL ARRAY `$GET[KEY]`